# How can I call "participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome:withCompletionHandler:"?

Tags: ios, game-center

I have a turn based game and am trying to end the game when someone forfeits from Game Center out of turn. I can't figure out what is called when the player out of turn actually presses the "forfeit" button. I want to implement,

```
participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome:withCompletionHandler:
```

but don't know where to put it and call it. I have tried to put it here:

```
-(void)handleTurnEventForMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match
```

and

```
- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:(GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController playerQuitForMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match
```

but neither seem to be called when a player presses the "forfeit" button out of turn. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to call `participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome:withCompletionHandler:` whenever you determine the user wants to forfeit—so in your case, when they tap the forfeit button (and possibly after hitting 'Yes' on a confirmation).

In that case, you'll want something like this:

```
-(void)playerChoseToForfeit {
    [self.match participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        //tell the user that they've forfeited (or not, if there's an error!)
    }];

}
```

Basically, it'll be in your own method—not (necessarily) a delegate one.

Comment: @username_tbd The problem I'm having is that the forfeit button is not a part of my view controller its a part of the Game Center MatchMaking view controller so I don't know what is getting called when they press it. If it is their own turn playerQuitForMatch is called, but it is not called when it is not their turn.

Answer (score 0):

Five years after you asked this question and Apple still hasn't updated the `GKLocalPlayerListener` protocol to handle this situation. I am also trying to rely solely on the Game Center MatchMaker view controller (GC MMVC) and I ran into the same problem you did, where if the user forfeits through the `GC MMVC` when it isn't their turn, then the match is left in a conflicted state: "completed" for the quitter, and "active" for the remaining players.

I found out by checking the `matchOutcome` of the opponent who quit out of turn after calling `match.loadMatchData`, that the opponent's outcome was set to `.quit`.

The reason that Game Center set the quitter's status to `.quit` but left the game active and set the `currentParticipant` to the next player was for games with more than two players. Since my game is a two-player only game, I didn't understand why `player(wantsToQuitMatch:)` wasn't being called.

So every time you call `loadMatchData`, you should check the `matchOutcome` of all other players and take appropriate action immediately. In my case, I set the quitter's outcome to `.lost`, the `localParticipant`'s outcome to `.won`, and then call `match.endMatchInTurn` with the updated match data. Then I will display the loaded match to the `localParticipant` with a message saying the other player quit.

If you don't call `match.endMatchInTurn` then the remaining player is left hanging with an active match but no active opponents.